# Multilanguage sitemap effect

Tags: seo, sitemap

Earlier our site had only one language, our primary language: Hungarian.

A few weeks ago, we upload the new site, with english language too (language is in subdirectory).

We made our new sitemap:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
  xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <url>
    <loc>http://dinox-h.hu</loc>
    <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="en"
                 href="http://dinox-h.hu/en/"
                 />

    <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="hu"
                 href="http://dinox-h.hu"
                 />
  </url>

  <url>
    <loc>http://dinox-h.hu/en/</loc>
    <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="hu"
                 href="http://dinox-h.hu"
                 />

     <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="en"
                 href="http://dinox-h.hu/en/"
                 />
  </url>


  <url>
    <loc>http://dinox-h.hu/cegbemutato.php</loc>
    <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="en"
                 href="http://dinox-h.hu/en/about-us.php"
                 />

    <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="hu"
                 href="http://dinox-h.hu/cegbemutato.php"
                 />
  </url>

  <url>
    <loc>http://dinox-h.hu/en/about-us.php</loc>
    <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="hu"
                 href="http://dinox-h.hu/cegbemutato.php"
                 />

     <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="en"
                 href="http://dinox-h.hu/en/about-us.php"
                 />
  </url>


   <url>
    <loc>http://dinox-h.hu/termekeink.php</loc>
    <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="en"
                 href="http://dinox-h.hu/en/products.php"
                 />

    <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="hu"
                 href="http://dinox-h.hu/termekeink.php"
                 />
  </url>

  <url>
    <loc>http://dinox-h.hu/en/products.php</loc>
    <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="hu"
                 href="http://dinox-h.hu/termekeink.php"
                 />

     <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="en"
                 href="http://dinox-h.hu/en/products.php"
                 />
  </url>

  <url>
    <loc>http://dinox-h.hu/standard_puffer_tartaly.php</loc>
    <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="en"
                 href="http://dinox-h.hu/en/standard-buffer-tanks.php"
                 />

    <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="hu"
                 href="http://dinox-h.hu/standard_puffer_tartaly.php"
                 />
  </url>

  <url>
    <loc>http://dinox-h.hu/en/standard-buffer-tanks.php</loc>
    <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="hu"
                 href="http://dinox-h.hu/standard_puffer_tartaly.php"
                 />

     <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="en"
                 href="http://dinox-h.hu/en/standard-buffer-tanks.php"
                 />
  </url>


    <url>
    <loc>http://dinox-h.hu/standard_belso_hocserlos.php</loc>
    <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="en"
                 href="http://dinox-h.hu/en/standard-internal-heat-exchanger.php"
                 />

    <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="hu"
                 href="http://dinox-h.hu/standard_belso_hocserlos.php"
                 />
  </url>

  <url>
    <loc>http://dinox-h.hu/en/standard-internal-heat-exchanger.php</loc>
    <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="hu"
                 href="http://dinox-h.hu/standard_belso_hocserlos.php"
                 />

     <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="en"
                 href="http://dinox-h.hu/en/standard-internal-heat-exchanger.php"
                 />
  </url>


   <url>
    <loc>http://dinox-h.hu/puffer_tartalyok.php</loc>
    <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="en"
                 href="http://dinox-h.hu/en/buffer-tanks.php"
                 />

    <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="hu"
                 href="http://dinox-h.hu/puffer_tartalyok.php"
                 />
  </url>

  <url>
    <loc>http://dinox-h.hu/en/buffer-tanks.php</loc>
    <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="hu"
                 href="http://dinox-h.hu/puffer_tartalyok.php"
                 />

     <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="en"
                 href="http://dinox-h.hu/en/buffer-tanks.php"
                 />
  </url>


  <url>
    <loc>http://dinox-h.hu/belso_hocserelos_tartalyok.php</loc>
    <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="en"
                 href="http://dinox-h.hu/en/internal-heat-exchanger-tanks.php"
                 />

    <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="hu"
                 href="http://dinox-h.hu/belso_hocserelos_tartalyok.php"
                 />
  </url>

  <url>
    <loc>http://dinox-h.hu/en/internal-heat-exchanger-tanks.php</loc>
    <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="hu"
                 href="http://dinox-h.hu/belso_hocserelos_tartalyok.php"
                 />

     <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="en"
                 href="http://dinox-h.hu/en/internal-heat-exchanger-tanks.php"
                 />
  </url>

   <url>
    <loc>http://dinox-h.hu/egyeb_tartalyok.php</loc>
    <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="en"
                 href="http://dinox-h.hu/en/other_tanks.php"
                 />

    <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="hu"
                 href="http://dinox-h.hu/egyeb_tartalyok.php"
                 />
  </url>

  <url>
    <loc>http://dinox-h.hu/en/other_tanks.php</loc>
    <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="hu"
                 href="http://dinox-h.hu/egyeb_tartalyok.php"
                 />

     <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="en"
                 href="http://dinox-h.hu/en/other_tanks.php"
                 />
  </url>

   <url>
    <loc>http://dinox-h.hu/egyedi_termekek.php</loc>
    <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="en"
                 href="http://dinox-h.hu/en/custom-products.php"
                 />

    <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="hu"
                 href="http://dinox-h.hu/egyedi_termekek.php"
                 />
  </url>

  <url>
    <loc>http://dinox-h.hu/en/custom-products.php</loc>
    <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="hu"
                 href="http://dinox-h.hu/egyedi_termekek.php"
                 />

     <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="en"
                 href="http://dinox-h.hu/en/custom-products.php"
                 />
  </url>

   <url>
    <loc>http://dinox-h.hu/galeria.php</loc>
    <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="en"
                 href="http://dinox-h.hu/en/gallery.php"
                 />

    <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="hu"
                 href="http://dinox-h.hu/galeria.php"
                 />
  </url>

  <url>
    <loc>http://dinox-h.hu/en/gallery.php</loc>
    <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="hu"
                 href="http://dinox-h.hu/galeria.php"
                 />

     <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="en"
                 href="http://dinox-h.hu/en/gallery.php"
                 />
  </url>

  <url>
    <loc>http://dinox-h.hu/standard_puffer_tartaly_galeria.php</loc>
    <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="en"
                 href="http://dinox-h.hu/en/standard-buffer-tanks-gallery.php"
                 />

    <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="hu"
                 href="http://dinox-h.hu/standard_puffer_tartaly_galeria.php"
                 />
  </url>

  <url>
    <loc>http://dinox-h.hu/en/standard-buffer-tanks-gallery.php</loc>
    <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="hu"
                 href="http://dinox-h.hu/standard_puffer_tartaly_galeria.php"
                 />

     <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="en"
                 href="http://dinox-h.hu/en/standard-buffer-tanks-gallery.php"
                 />
  </url>

   <url>
    <loc>http://dinox-h.hu/standard_belso_hocserlos_galeria.php</loc>
    <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="en"
                 href="http://dinox-h.hu/en/standard-internal-heat-exchanger-gallery.php"
                 />

    <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="hu"
                 href="http://dinox-h.hu/standard_belso_hocserlos_galeria.php"
                 />
  </url>

  <url>
    <loc>http://dinox-h.hu/en/standard-internal-heat-exchanger-gallery.php</loc>
    <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="hu"
                 href="http://dinox-h.hu/standard_belso_hocserlos_galeria.php"
                 />

     <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="en"
                 href="http://dinox-h.hu/en/standard-internal-heat-exchanger-gallery.php"
                 />
  </url>

     <url>
    <loc>http://dinox-h.hu/puffer_tartalyok_galeria.php</loc>
    <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="en"
                 href="http://dinox-h.hu/en/buffer-tanks-gallery.php"
                 />

    <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="hu"
                 href="http://dinox-h.hu/puffer_tartalyok_galeria.php"
                 />
  </url>

  <url>
    <loc>http://dinox-h.hu/en/buffer-tanks-gallery.php</loc>
    <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="hu"
                 href="http://dinox-h.hu/puffer_tartalyok_galeria.php"
                 />

     <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="en"
                 href="http://dinox-h.hu/en/buffer-tanks-gallery.php"
                 />
  </url>

    <url>
    <loc>http://dinox-h.hu/belso_hocserelos_tartalyok_galeria.php</loc>
    <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="en"
                 href="http://dinox-h.hu/en/internal-heat-exchanger-tanks-gallery.php"
                 />

    <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="hu"
                 href="http://dinox-h.hu/belso_hocserelos_tartalyok_galeria.php"
                 />
  </url>

  <url>
    <loc>http://dinox-h.hu/en/internal-heat-exchanger-tanks-gallery.php</loc>
    <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="hu"
                 href="http://dinox-h.hu/belso_hocserelos_tartalyok_galeria.php"
                 />

     <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="en"
                 href="http://dinox-h.hu/en/internal-heat-exchanger-tanks-gallery.php"
                 />
  </url>

      <url>
    <loc>http://dinox-h.hu/egyeb_tartalyok_galeria.php</loc>
    <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="en"
                 href="http://dinox-h.hu/en/other-tanks-gallery.php"
                 />

    <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="hu"
                 href="http://dinox-h.hu/egyeb_tartalyok_galeria.php"
                 />
  </url>

  <url>
    <loc>http://dinox-h.hu/en/other-tanks-gallery.php</loc>
    <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="hu"
                 href="http://dinox-h.hu/egyeb_tartalyok_galeria.php"
                 />

     <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="en"
                 href="http://dinox-h.hu/en/other-tanks-gallery.php"
                 />
  </url>

      <url>
    <loc>http://dinox-h.hu/egyedi_termekek_galeria.php</loc>
    <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="en"
                 href="http://dinox-h.hu/en/custom-products-gallery.php"
                 />

    <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="hu"
                 href="http://dinox-h.hu/egyedi_termekek_galeria.php"
                 />
  </url>

  <url>
    <loc>http://dinox-h.hu/en/custom-products-gallery.php</loc>
    <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="hu"
                 href="http://dinox-h.hu/egyedi_termekek_galeria.php"
                 />

     <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="en"
                 href="http://dinox-h.hu/en/custom-products-gallery.php"
                 />
  </url>

   <url>
    <loc>http://dinox-h.hu/rolunk_galeria.php</loc>
    <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="en"
                 href="http://dinox-h.hu/en/aboutus-gallery.php"
                 />

    <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="hu"
                 href="http://dinox-h.hu/rolunk_galeria.php"
                 />
  </url>

  <url>
    <loc>http://dinox-h.hu/en/aboutus-gallery.php</loc>
    <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="hu"
                 href="http://dinox-h.hu/rolunk_galeria.php"
                 />

     <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="en"
                 href="http://dinox-h.hu/en/aboutus-gallery.php"
                 />
  </url>

    <url>
    <loc>http://dinox-h.hu/elerhetosegek.php</loc>
    <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="en"
                 href="http://dinox-h.hu/en/contacts.php"
                 />

    <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="hu"
                 href="http://dinox-h.hu/elerhetosegek.php"
                 />
  </url>

  <url>
    <loc>http://dinox-h.hu/en/contacts.php</loc>
    <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="hu"
                 href="http://dinox-h.hu/elerhetosegek.php"
                 />

     <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="en"
                 href="http://dinox-h.hu/en/contacts.php"
                 />
  </url>

</urlset>
```

(http://pastebin.com/djKhi2xR).

Before we made this changes we were on the first page in Google for many keyword. Now we are nowhere.

Should I check our sitemap, or what might be the problem?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because there does not seem to be a programming problem.


Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have something wrong with cookies and redirects.  When I first visit URLs in your site map, the 302 redirect to a version with a double slash.   Later when I have a cookie and I fetch them again, they don't redirect.

For example `http://dinox-h.hu/en/gallery.php` redirects to `http://dinox-h.hu//en/gallery.php`

This could cause your site not to be indexed because:

- You are redirecting away from URLs in your sitemap when the user (or googlebot) has no cookies
- The redirect is a 302 which does not pass pagerank.

---

```
$ curl -s -D - http://dinox-h.hu/galeria.php | head -n 30
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Thu, 18 Jul 2013 17:02:39 GMT
Server: Apache
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=j22vjbjvj8n63ma1foalm5ujp0; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Location: http://dinox-h.hu//en/gallery.php
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
....
```

Comment: I have an automatic redirect if user browser's language is different than hungarian. Maybe this is wrong. Could you help me how do you debug this? Where can i check this redirection?

Comment: If you redirect automatically the Googlebot won't be able to crawl your site and you will lose rankings.  (Googlebot doesn't send language information).  It is better to put up a notice on the site that says "I see you speak English, click here for the English version".

Comment: I fixed de redirection error.  But than i disable this function. Maybe thats tha reason why google not index hungarian content?

Comment: So i disabled auto-redirect as your suggestion. Any other think i should do? My sitemap is ok? May i wrong if i think Google have to manage which content will shown (english or hungarian) in search result depending which google search domain used? (google.hu or google.com?!)